# Layout page not loading in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've created a strongly typed view selected a layout page

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_xyzLayout.cshtml";
}
```

but this layout page never gets loaded when I run the page

[Layout Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLOfu.png)

Comment: You're presenting a view page, can you show `_xyzLayout.cshtml` layout page code?

Comment: I've upladed an image of layout page

Comment: @Tetsuya Other views are loading perfectly with layout page but only this view is not loading with loading page

Comment: Have you getting error in browser console with only this view page? What fulfills the criteria "not loading" (CSS, JS or all embedded files)?

Comment: Just try to comment some code and try to debug it

Comment: Its not reaching the layout page

Comment: Layout page is loading but css is not loading

Comment: Which style sheet not loaded? I seen `icon-font-min.css` and some others using local path, make sure they're loaded properly (use `Url.Content` and/or `~/` prefix for those paths).

Comment: No style sheet got loaded only on this view else other views are working fne with this layout

Comment: Tried with @Url.Content("") thats even not working

Answer (score 0):

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false) u can call this code inside the layout page

Then u call every page @Rendersection scripts{
Your scripts}

@RenderSection("styles", required: false) also

http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/layouts-renderbody-rendersection-and-renderpage-in-aspnet-mvc

Refer this page

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the controller routing to the page uses a View method call. For example

public ActionResult Details(int  custid )
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer(id =2, Name = "Dipo")

```
        return View(customer);
    }
```